# In Bootstrap 4, how can you make a non-navbar div sticky to the top of the window on scrolling?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the following div structure of my content window, using BS4 framework:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 ...
  <div class="row">
   ... 
    <div class="container">
     ...
       <div class="row row-grid">
        ...
         <div class="col-8"> <!-- my left sided content, long block of cards-->
         ...
         <div class="col-4"> <!-- my right sided card-block that I need to be sticky and follow the left as user scrolls down-->
```

I see in the docs that the `nav-bar` has a `.sticky-top` class - but when I try to use this in my example here things get wonky.

How can I just get my `col-4` div to stick to the top of the browser window, when the user scrolls to see the content in the `col-8` div?

**Clarification**
My right and left content divs live under other static content, like the navbar and a header block. So on page load, the right (sticky) div should be in it's native position, and only stick to the top of the window when scrolling beyond it's visibilty. I've updated the fiddle to show kind of what I mean.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hematogones/74b3nmur/)

Answer (score 2):

Use position: fixed css property

CSS

```
.fixed-div{
  position : fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically after `position: sticky;`; unfortunately, browser support is still [somewhat lacking](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky). If you only care about browsers that support it, the syntax is similar to:

```
.sticky // or whatever selector you want to use
{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 75px;
}
```

See the [MDN article for `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#Sticky_positioning) for a better explanation, but, to put it simply, the value of `top` is the distance from the top of the viewport (or the nearest positioned container) where the element switches from static to fixed positioning. It's the same affect that the Affix plugin provides in Bootstrap 3.